# Getting 'Invalid Argument' error in PL/SQL block

Tags: plsql

The following PL/SQL will not execute and simply returns 'Invalid Argument' as an error.   I've gone as far as commenting out eavery line one by one and I can vary the error I receive but I cannot get the proc to run as I cannot identify where the error lies and it may well lie in permissions or the executing user but any help will be received gratefully.  Here's the proc

```sql
DECLARE
    ind NUMBER;             -- Loop index 
    h1 NUMBER;              -- Data Pump job handle 
    percent_done NUMBER;    -- Percentage of job complete 
    job_state VARCHAR2(30); -- To keep track of job state 
    le ku$_LogEntry;        -- For WIP and error messages 
    js ku$_JobStatus;       -- The job status from get_status 
    jd ku$_JobDesc;         -- The job description from get_status 
    sts ku$_Status;         -- The status object returned by get_status 
BEGIN
    h1 := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN('EXPORT','SCHEMA',NULL,'SQL_INSTALLER_01152009_1014','LATEST');
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1,'SQL_INSTALLER_01152009_1014.dmp','ORACLE_SCRIPT_RUNNER_BACKUP',NULL,1);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(h1,'SQL_INSTALLER_01152009_1014.log','ORACLE_SCRIPT_RUNNER_BACKUP',NULL,3);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h1, 'SCHEMA_LIST','''speccs_web_test''', NULL, NULL);
    DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(h1);

    percent_done := 0;
    job_state := 'UNDEFINED';
    while (job_state != 'COMPLETED') and (job_state != 'STOPPED') loop 
        dbms_datapump.get_status(
            h1,
            dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error +
            dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_status +
            dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip,
            -1,
            job_state,
            sts);

        js := sts.job_status;
        if js.percent_done != percent_done then 
            percent_done := js.percent_done;
        end if;

        if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_wip) != 0) then 
            le := sts.wip;
        else 
            if (bitand(sts.mask,dbms_datapump.ku$_status_job_error) != 0) then 
                le := sts.error;
            else 
                le := null;
            end if;
        end if;

        if le is not null then 
            ind := le.FIRST;
            while ind is not null loop 
                ind := le.NEXT(ind);
            end loop;
        end if;
    end loop;
    dbms_datapump.detach(h1); 
END;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular problem it is because the schema_name speccs_web_test is not in upper case.  SPECCS_WEB_TEST is fine and the proc is now running ;)

Answer (score 1):

I found something:

See here: http://petermag.blogspot.com/2008/01/export-datapump-how-to-do-via-plsql.html

You get an invalid argument error error when the dump file already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can download SQL Developer and use its debugger (it is free).

See here: http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/products/sql/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks there chap.  I have continued debugging and have nailed it down to one line..

DBMS_DATAPUMP.METADATA_FILTER(h1, 'SCHEMA_LIST','''speccs_web_test''', NULL, NULL);

This is the one.  Comment it out and all is swell. The error is indicating one of these values is not valid and I would hazard a guess it's the odd looking '''speccs_web_test''' but searches seem to indicate this is correct, this is because that parameter is a list and haven can be '(''name'', ''name''); which translates to ('name', 'name') a valid format for an IN list.

I'll probably sort it in a minute or two but you think i'd of nailed it hours ago :)